# Helm test fails with ERROR: watch closed before UntilWithoutRetry timeout

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When I do helm test as follows:

```
helm test black-box-7b6979c6-tester --debug --timeout 7200 > ./helm_test.log 2>&1 &
```

Test fails with the following log:

```
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '33023'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:33023"
RUNNING: black-box-7b6979c6-tester-integration-tests
ERROR: watch closed before UntilWithoutRetry timeout
Error: 1 test(s) failed
```

The test pod runs integration test with maven and when streaming the logs in test pod with `kubectl logs -f` the maven is continuing to download artifacts and then it gets terminated abruptly with the error:

`rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error: No such container: <long container id>`

```
Downloading from xxx: <url to pom>
Downloading from xxx: <url to pom>
Downloading from xxx: <url to pom>
Downloading from xxx: <url to pom>
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error: No such container: 9014ef540248895b62e1953d7158f87bc4fe18f138677355f78e7961e44eca2f
```

Neither did I find anything wrong with the pod or the installation (I'm able to stream the logs) nor could I find anything much about the error.

More info on environment:

Nodes run RHEL 7.6

```
+ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.2", GitCommit:"cff46ab41ff0bb44d8584413b598ad8360ec1def", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-01-10T23:35:51Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12+", GitVersion:"v1.12.3-1+fee411aca93f0e", GitCommit:"fee411aca93f0e786995cc125cf8f9783484f958", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-04T06:45:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

+ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.12.3", GitCommit:"eecf22f77df5f65c823aacd2dbd30ae6c65f186e", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.12.1", GitCommit:"02a47c7249b1fc6d8fd3b94e6b4babf9d818144e", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Comment: Post more details of the environment.

Comment: Added details more details of the env

Comment: Can you provide logs from the `POD`? Can you add `--debug` to the helm test?

Comment: added logs from pod + added --debug to helm test

Comment: I understand this `POD` fails on downloading the image, at least the what I can see from logs. Can you try to run ` docker pull <your_image>:<version>`

Comment: No, the pod fails while downloading maven artifacts. I managed to get it working by reducing the timeout to 600 and caching the maven artifacts before running the test so that the number of downloads is reduced. Seems there is a problem with long timeout in helm test